# Can we explicitly call a virtual `operator delete`?

Tags: c++, clang++, automated-refactoring

For reasons I wish not go into in depth here, I need to fully instrument allocations and deallocations in a large, existing code base, which makes use of custom `operator new` and `operator delete`. To this end, I am rewriting (using a clang frontend pass) every occurrence of `new X(...)` with `new (allocate<X>()) X(...)`, where the default implementation of `allocate<X>` calls out to the class-specific `operator new`, if it exists, or `::operator new` otherwise. I know that this is not 100% sound, but it is "good enough" for the code base I am targeting.

Now I'm trying to introduce a similar intercepting behavior for `delete`, but this is harder than expected, due to the weird nature of virtual `operator delete`. From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete:

> The call to the class-specific `T::operator delete` on a polymorphic class is the only case where a static member function is called through dynamic dispatch.

Consider the following example:

```
struct A {
    virtual ~A() { cout << "~A" << endl; }
    static void operator delete(void* ptr) {
        cout << "A::operator delete" << endl;
        ::operator delete(ptr);
    }
};
struct B : public A {
    virtual ~B() { cout << "~B" << endl; }
    static void operator delete(void* ptr) {
        cout << "B::operator delete" << endl;
        ::operator delete(ptr);
    }
};
```

Ideally I would want to replace each occurrence of `delete x` in the code base with `deleteWrapper(x)`, which is equivalent to `delete x` by default, but which I can add extra instrumentation to and specialize it for certain types of `x` if needed.

I thought I could do something like the following to achieve this:

```
template <typename T>
void deleteWrapper(T* x) {
  x->~T();
  // The deallocation behavior here should "tweakable" for certain types 
  // of T, for example I might need different implementations for 
  // std::pair<int, int> and std::pair<std::string, int>
  x->operator delete(x);
}
```

But (aside from invoking undefined behavior) this is not equivalent to `delete x`: With the above type hierarchy, `deleteWrapper(static_cast<A*>(new B))` calls `A::operator delete` instead of `B::operator delete`. Is there a way to call the correct overload, given a polymorphic pointer, without using `delete`?

If there is a solution which involves a certain amount of source rewriting, I would be interested to hear about it as well since I am already using a modified clang.

Comment: Would using your custom smart pointer class a solution?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to put the instrumentation into the class-specific (and/or globally replaced) versions of `operator new()` and `operator delete()`, rather than trying to edit every occurrence of a `new` or a `delete` expression?   It would be a rare program that has more than a moderate number of overloaded/replaced versions of those functions, whereas the number of `new` and `delete` expressions can be huge.

Comment: @Peter WebKit has many classes with operator new/delete overloaded to have objects either on a „fast-alloc“ heap or even type-specific isolated heaps. Sometimes I want different special casing of operator new/delete even for different instantiations of the same  template, which would involve non-trivial rewrites. I discussed the use case with n.m which has been moved to chat.